# How to get query result in devel?

Tags: 8

In Admin we have

http://domain.com/devel/php

I added query

```
$result = db_query("SELECT name FROM `users_field_data`");

print ($result);
```

It's not showing result. How to show that?

Comment: `foreach ($result as $item) {
     echo $item->name;
}` works as well

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Kint module (comes with devel) then do

`kint($result->__toString());` or `kint($result->arguments());`

Answer (score 0):

Using the module Devel Kint, you can use it to dump the variable to the screen.

```
kint($result);
```

If you do not have Devel Kint enabled, or simply want a different option, this page shows all the different ways you can debug using the Devel module.

http://ratatosk.net/drupal/tutorials/debugging-drupal.html

Answer (score 0):

In the devel module, we can't use the print.
like below, we have to use.

```
 $query = db_select('users_field_data', 'n');
    $query  ->fields('n', array('name ', 'name'));
    $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
   dpq($query); // Display the query. 

   dvr($result);// Dispaly the result
```

[image]